# Importing VCF files

Tags: import

I’ve got a client with a fair number of Contacts on his personal computer in VCF format. I’m curious if anyone has looked at importing VCF files into CiviCRM?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a direct answer, but this looks like a pretty quick and suprisingly awesome way to convert to csv:

https://www.hostpapa.com/knowledgebase/convert-vcf-files-csv-email-contacts/

EDIT: in case above link goes bad:

In windows all users have a `C:\users\your name\Contacts` folder. If you navigate there in windows explorer the ribbon gives you an import button which then allows you to import the vcf files. Then you can export them as csv.

Comment: I’ll point my client to hostpapa and will report back!

Comment: Ah client is on a Mac - any other ideas?

Comment: What about -> https://medium.com/@ablitst1/converting-vcards-to-csv-files-16865af70232

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT if the contacts are on iCloud (where the .vcfs may have been exported from originally right), see for example https://www.maketecheasier.com/export-icloud-contacts-csv/